# Why does lapply mangle POSIXlt?

Tags: r

It appears that `lapply` mangles `POSIXlt` records:

```
> hours
[1] "2016-01-01 00:00:00 GMT" "2016-01-01 01:00:00 GMT" "2016-01-01 02:00:00 GMT"
> str(hours)
 POSIXlt[1:3], format: "2016-01-01 00:00:00" "2016-01-01 01:00:00" "2016-01-01 02:00:00"
> dput(hours)
structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L), hour = 0:2, 
    mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(116L, 
    116L, 116L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L), yday = c(0L, 0L, 0L), 
    isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
"mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")
> read.csv(file.path(data.dir,strftime(hours[1],"%Y%d%m%H.csv")))
.... success ....
> lapply(hours, function (h) read.csv(file.path(data.dir,strftime(h,"%Y%d%m%H.csv"))))
Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) (from #1) : 'origin' must be supplied
Calls: lapply -> FUN -> read.csv -> read.table -> file.path -> strftime -> format -> as.POSIXlt -> as.POSIXlt.numeric
> lapply(hours,function(h) {
+  print(h)
+  str(h)
+  read.csv(file.path(data.dir,strftime(h,"%Y%m%d%H.csv")))
+  })
+ . + [1] 0 0 0
 num [1:3] 0 0 0
Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) (from #1) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

IOW, elements of `hours` in the function inside `lapply` are numeric vectors, not `POSIXlt`.

It looks like `hours` is a list of individual `POSIXlt` fields, rather than a vector or `POSIXlt` objects.

what am I doing wrong?

PS. The following appears to be a work-around:

```
lapply(1:length(hours),function(i) ....hours[i]...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`POSIXlt` objects are a named list of vectors (see `?POSIXlt`). `lapply` loops over the list and calls `FUN` on each vector (`"sec"`, `"min"`, ..., `"isdst"`).

This is similar to how `data.frame` objects are a list of vectors, so `lapply` loops over the columns of the data.frame and calls `FUN` on each vector.

A better work-around would be to convert your `POSIXlt` object to `POSIXct`, unless you need specific functionality from `POSIXlt`.